# Extjs 4 with extjs 3 calendar?

Tags: extjs, calendar, extjs4, extjs3

I'm on extjs 4 and I try to find a compatible calendar for extjs 4 
(I try : http://ext.ensible.com/products/calendar/ but it's doesn't work with extjs 4..)
I searched  and I didn't find anything..

Another solution would be to use extjs 3 calendar in sandbox with my app on extjs 4, but I have no idea how to do it.
( My apps likes the layout-browser example have a tree menu on the left, and onclick on one node I want to print my calendar in the center panel .
My central panel is a vcard, so I just have to change the active item, but I don't know how to set an active item with extjs 3 (my calendar !) )

Ps: it's not for a commercial use, so something "free" if it's possible

Thanks for you help !

Answer (score 1):

The Extensible version is currently Ext 4 compatible in Github (in progress, but mostly working). The official Ext calendar example will be upgraded in Ext 4.1.

Comment: I just downloaded your version on Github, and test to modify basic.html example with my ext-all.css and ext-all-debug.js from extjs 4 +        extensible-all.css  and extensible-all-debug.js from ensible.com it's didn't work . A I'm missing something to include ? (Ext-overrides, Extensible.js ? )                         thx.

Comment: The README currently has a warning that the transition to Ext 4 is still in progress, and that things might not yet be fully working, so YMMV.  However, earlier today I did update most of the examples and the basic example should work fine -- are you certain that your include paths are correct (double-checked in the console)? Also, when you say "download" -- the current packaged zip is for Ext 3.x. Make sure you are using the most current source from the master branch. There will not be a packaged release for Ext 4 until everything is complete (probably another week or two).

Comment: I just tried again, and it didn't work : In console I have  : ddm.fireEvents.createSequence is not a function
[Stopper sur une erreur] ddm.fireEvents = ddm.fireEvents.createSequence(onFire, ddm);
extens...ebug.js (ligne 1150)
Ext.ensible.cal.EventMappings is undefined
[Stopper sur une erreur] property: Ext.ensible.cal.EventMappings.StartDate.name,
Memory...tore.js (ligne 32)
Ext.ensible.sample.MemoryEventStore is not a constructor
[Stopper sur une erreur] data: Ext.ensible.sample.EventData

Comment: What I do : include /extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css , /extjs/ext-all-debug.js (from extjs 4)                                                                   Downloaded your example from github (updated 2 hours ago)                        and include /resources/css/extensible-all.css , /extensible-all-debug.js from extensible 1.0 ( from here: https://github.com/bmoeskau/Extensible/downloads ).  I don't know what I'm missing .                                                                    Ps : I double check my includes, they are good.

Answer (score 0):

Use the sandbox ext4 example entitled "Ext JS 3 & 4 on one page"

Comment: Thx, I'm looking at him, but there are any docs :/                     So for extjs 4 I must  prefix with ext4 everything except the calendar on extjs 3, prefix with "extjs" (By default) ?

Comment: I tried the sandbox (simple viewport with extjs 4, and on the center region an item: 

Code:
items: {
                    // xtype is supported:
                   xtype: 'extensible.calendarpanel',
                    eventStore: eventStore
                                    }
(I copied / paste this code from windows calendar example) and i got an error in ext-all-sandbox.js: "namespace is undefined" .
It's came from the xtype . (When I comment xtype... the error disapear ).
I also try : " xtype: 'Ext.ensible.cal.CalendarPanel',"
any idea ?
Sorry for my bad english..

Answer (score 0):

extensible-1.5.0-beta1 (https://github.com/bmoeskau/Extensible/downloads) works with Ext JS 4. I have tried the basic calendar example and it is working fine (except for 1 or 2 missing images). However, you MUST place the extension directory as a sibling of the Ext JS directory (i.e. both these should be in one directory) and also, rename the Ext JS directory (which originally has the version attached to it) to just "extjs". This will fix everything!